# Update rhandsontable by changing one cell value

Tags: r, rhandsontable

I have the dataframe below:

```
DF2 = data.frame(agency_postcode = factor(rep(c(12345,45678,24124,32525,32325),2)),
                 car_group=factor(rep(c("Microcar","City car","Supermini","Compact","SUV"),2)),
                 transmission=factor(rep(c("automatic","manual"),5)))
```

and after subseting it by one of the values of the 1st column

```
newdata <- DF2[ which(DF2$agency_postcode =='12345'), ]
```

and re-factoring in order to set accordingly the dropdown values of the second and third column to only available values after the subset

```
for(i in 2:ncol(newdata)){
  newdata[,i] <- factor(newdata[,i])
}
```

I display it with:

```
library(rhandsontable)
rhandsontable(newdata[1,], rowHeaders = NULL, width = 550, height = 300)%>%
  hot_col(colnames(newdata))
```

What I want to do is when I select a different value from the available ones of (only) the 1st column the whole table should be updated accordingly if of course this row exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to assign the **newdata** dataframe and the **postcode** selected as reactive values and trigger the render function using this reactive value. A working example.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)


ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("RHandsontable"),
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(),
      mainPanel(
         rHandsontableOutput("test")
      )
   )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  # Assign value of 12345 as default to postcode for the default table rendering
  values <- reactiveValues(postcode = "12345",tabledata = data.frame())

  # An observer which will check the value assigned to postcode variable and create the sample dataframe
  observeEvent(values$postcode,{
    DF2 = data.frame(agency_postcode = factor(rep(c(12345,45678,24124,32525,32325),2)),
                     car_group=factor(rep(c("Microcar","City car","Supermini","Compact","SUV"),2)),
                     transmission=factor(rep(c("automatic","manual"),5)))
  # Created dataframe is assigned to a reactive dataframe 'tabledata'
    values$tabledata <- DF2[ which(DF2$agency_postcode ==values$postcode), ]
    for(i in 2:ncol(values$tabledata)){
      values$tabledata[,i] <- factor(values$tabledata[,i])
    }
  })

  # Capture changes made in the first column of table and assign the value to the postcode reactive variable. This would then trigger the previous observer
  observeEvent(input$test$changes$changes,{
    col <- input$test$changes$changes[[1]][[2]]
    if(col==0){
      values$postcode <- input$test$changes$changes[[1]][[4]]
    }
  })

 # Use the reactive df 'tabledata' to render.
  output$test <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(values$tabledata[1,], rowHeaders = NULL, width = 550, height = 300)%>%
      hot_col(colnames(values$tabledata)) 
  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: a great approach

Comment: Could you please explain me how I could do the same for the first 2 columns that when would change would change the third as well?If exists such row of course

Comment: You would need to add another observer that listens to value changes in second column and trigger rendering the table again. I will try to post a working code snippet soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot you save me

Comment: Basically I created a new a little bit more complex Question based on your answer as it is more fair to gain reputation points by answering it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937662/change-cells-based-on-modifications-of-other-cells-in-rhandsontable-of-a-shiny-a

Comment: Added an answer there :)